# libspotify register device for remote control

Tags: spotify, libspotify

Firstly, what I would like to achieve. I am building media system using Raspberry Pi device. So far there is mopidy service which as far as I know uses libspotify to play music from Spotify. Everything works really well. Except I would like to control my Raspberry Spotify playback from my desktop Spotify client or from my Android phone. Official clients do allow this feature to switch device.

I would like to implement same feature using libspotify.

I'm not even sure if it's possible using public API.

Any ideas how to achieve such thing are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Libspotify does not expose Spotify connect functionality. It's a limitation of the library and Spotify show no interest in improving it. So, this is not possible.